# how to recreate a working CURL command with Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

This curl command works as desired:

```
curl -H "X-Api-Key:j65k423lj4k2l3fds" `
     -X PUT `
     -d "alerts_enabled=true" `
        https://some/working/file.xml
```

How can I recreate this natively in PS with `Invoke-WebRequest`? I've tried

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"X-Api-Key" = "j65k423lj4k2l3fds"} `
                  -Method PUT `
                  -Body "alerts_enabled=true" `
                  -Uri https://some/working/file.xml
```

I've also tried making objects for all the params (e.g. `$headers = @{"X-Api-Key" = "Key:j65k423lj4k2l3fds"}` and passing `-Headers $headers`).

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

got it to work natively using invoke-webrequest. powershell guru here at work helped me out. Switched to the New Relic API version 2 (available at https://rpm.newrelic.com/api/explore), which uses JSON instead of xml, and made some sytax tweaks.

```
$json = @"{"alert_policy":[{"enabled":"true"}]"@

$headers = @{}
$headers["X-Api-Key"] = "j65k423lj4k2l3fds"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://some/working/file.json" -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Method Post
```

Comment: although the code above was producing a 200, and some response json, it was not toggling the setting in New Relic.  I was POSTing instead of PUTing...so pay attention to that.

Answer (score 26):

Try adding the parameter -ContentType e.g.:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"X-Api-Key" = "j65k423lj4k2l3fds"} -Method PUT `
                  -Body "alerts_enabled=true" -Uri https://some/working/file.xml `
                  -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

That results in a request that looks like this (from Fiddler):

```
PUT http://some/working/file.xml HTTP/1.1
X-Api-Key: j65k423lj4k2l3fds
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 6.2; en-US) WindowsPowerShell/5.0.9701.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: some
Content-Length: 19
Expect: 100-continue

alerts_enabled=true
```

For testing, I changed the URL from https to http.  If that doesn't work, go download Fiddler and inspect the RAW request when curl is used to see what is different.

Comment: When are quotes needed - as in the `body` and when not as in `-uri`? My curl I want to convert to ps starts with `curl -s -k -m 5` so I have to find out the flag names as methods in `ps`. As body - `-d` - I have a xml file, maybe I can put that in another file to have it well formatted.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me [in Powershell using the `curl` alias to `Invoke-WebRequest`](http://thesociablegeek.com/azure/using-curl-in-powershell/)...

```
 curl -H @{"X-Api-Key" = "j65k423lj4k2l3fds"} -Method PUT 'https://some/working/file.xml'
```