# POST request with Powershell 2.0 using cURL

Tags: rest, powershell, curl

### Scenario

Among other things, Powershell 2.0 doesn't have the useful cmdlet Invoke-RestMethod.

I can't upgrade to version 3 and most examples I've found use version 3.

I have found [this article](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/7e7b6bf2-d067-48c3-96b3-b38f26a1d143/), which seems, however, too complicated for my simple scenario.

I need to write a Powershell script that POSTs data in Json format, e.g.

```
{"Id":5,"Email":"test@com","DataFields":null,"Status":0}
```

### What I've tried

I am able to GET data. This is one of the scripts I have tried.

```
curl -v --user username:password https://api.dotmailer.com/v2/account-info
```

But, when I try to POST, I can't figure out where to put the body of the message in the script. This is what I've got so far:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u username:password -d '{"Id":5,"Email":"test@com","OptInType":0,"EmailType":0, "DataFields":null,"Status":0}' https://api.dotmailer.com/v2/contacts`

which returns the following error:

`{"message":"Could not parse the body of the request based on the content type \"application/json\" ERROR_BODY_DOES_NOT_MATCH_CONTENT_TYPE"}*`

### Question

Can anyone advise on how to POST Json data from Powershell using cURL?

Any pointers to why I get the error I mentioned in the Waht I've tried section would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919414/powershell-http-post-rest-api-basic-authentication

Comment: @DavidBrabant I have seen that question and I don't think mine is a duplicate because I am not asking about basic authentication.

Comment: Ehmm. Actually, you are. "I need to write a Powershell script that POSTs data in Json format and **uses basic authentication**". AFAIK, to post JSON you should just convert it to bytes with UTF8 encoding and set `application/json` as content type. So cut and paste the relevant parts from the linked question, where `$Post = '{"Id":5,"Email":"test@com","DataFields":null,"Status":0}'`

Comment: @FrodeF. Fair enough, I've edited the question to avoid that (I do know how to write the basic auth bit). Also I've edited the title as it was unclear: I want to use cURL commands and run them in powershell.

Comment: if anyone needs answer for this please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23556669/4192663

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that **the question is about the `curl.exe` *external program***, not about PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet (which, unfortunately, is *aliased to `curl`* in later PowerShell versions, preempting calls to the external program unless the `.exe` extension is explicitly specified (`curl.exe ...`).

Unfortunately and unexpectedly, **you have to `\`-escape embedded `"` instances in a string you pass as an argument to an *external program* in *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.2.x***.

That is, the following works *only in v7.3+*:

```bash
# Only works in PowerShell 7.3+
'{"Id":5,"Email":"test@com","DataFields":null,"Status":0}'
```

*Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x-* require:

```bash
# Manual \-escaping of " required in
# *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell (Core) 7.2.x-*
'{\"Id\":5,\"Email\":\"test@com\",\"DataFields\":null,\"Status\":0}'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

From curl's [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) it appears you need to use `-d` switch:

```
curl -v --user username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Id":5,"Email":"test@com","DataFields":null,"Status":0}' https://api.dotmailer.com/v2/contacts
```

Comment: Thanks, however the command you provided returns the following error: `{"message":"Content type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" is not supported. Please use one of: application/json,application/xml ERROR_CONTENT_TYPE_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED"}*`

Comment: Edited the answer to add required header.

Comment: Your edited answer returns the error I mentioned in the 'What I've tried' section above. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, it is a valid json.. try adding square brackets around the body: `-d '[{"Id":5,"Email":"test@com","DataFields":null,"Status":0}]'` or double quotes around values `-d '{"Id":"5","Email":"test@com","DataFields":"null","Status":"0"}'` or both.

Comment: Done that, but no joy.

Comment: Try using pure powershell, this could help: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0085e084-cff3-422d-98c2-00d2cfeae815/cannot-post-data-to-http-page?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: This answer doesn't work, because the JSON string must have its embedded `"` chars. escaped as `\"`, due to being passed to an _external program_ (`curl.exe`) - hard to believe, but true; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) for more information.