# Powershell is eating quotes in a GitHub action

Tags: powershell, github-actions

I have this line in a GitHub Action:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/JJ/raku-advent-calendar-article-2019/issues/$ENV:ISSUE/comments -H "Authorization: token $ENV:TOKEN"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data $output
```

I haven't found a way to assign values to `$data` to make it work. GitHub Actions, or Powershell, or both, cut it, generally at a quote, but I really couldn't find out what it does and where.

This was the last I tried:

```
'{ `"body`": `"Merry Xmas to you too!`"}'
```

Note the Powershell-escapes for the double quotes. This returned this error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Xmas
```

So, for some reason, it stopped at Merry. Any idea?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914244/post-request-with-powershell-2-0-using-curl) is similar, however, they are not using a variable to hold the result, which I need.

Comment: As an aside: The [linked question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24929803/45375) doesn't actually work, and the basic problem is the same as here.

Comment: Curl is actually an alias for invoke-webrequest in powershell for windows.

Comment: Good point, @js2010, but the syntax of the command in the question and the error message imply that it is the `curl` utility (external program) that is being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using PowerShell, use the native PowerShell functions, like `Invoke-RestMethod`, which accept PowerShell data structures instead of worrying about serialization/deserialization.

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization = "token $env:TOKEN"; "Content-Type" = "application/json"} -Body @{body = "Merry Xmas to you too!"}
```

Answer (score 3):

- **`'...'` are *verbatim* strings in PowerShell**, so **embedded `"` require *no* escaping** - your `` ` `` chars. are treated as *literals*.
- However, sadly, **PowerShell's handling of embedded `"` when calling *external programs* such as `curl` is fundamentally broken, requiring you to *manually* `\`*-escape them* in *all PowerShell versions up to v7.2.x***.

  - This long-standing problem is **fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7.3+**, but with selective exceptions on Windows - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

Therefore:

```
$jsonForCurl = '{ \"body\": \"Merry Xmas to you too!\" }'
```

To apply this escaping to an existing string value, programmatically, use the following:

```
$json = '{ "body": "Merry Xmas to you too!" }'
$jsonForCurl = $json -replace '"', '\"'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55604316/45375) for how to apply this technique to *expandable* strings (`"..."`) and for how to make the regex more robust to also deal with preexisting `\"` sequences in the data correctly.