# HTTP server missing quotes in JSON body?

Tags: powershell, go

I tried some example from github and:

```
package main

import(
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
)

//User defines model for storing account details in database
type User struct {
    Username string
    //Password string `json:"-"`
    //IsAdmin bool
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

func main(){
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/echo", echoHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", mux)
}

func echoHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    user := User{} //initialize empty user
    var bodyBuffer = new(bytes.Buffer)
    bodyBuffer.ReadFrom(r.Body)
    bodyBytes := bodyBuffer.Bytes()
    fmt.Println("Received Body: ", string(bodyBytes[:]))
    err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &user)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(userJson)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type","application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

And when I call curl from powershell:

```
curl -d '{"Username":"noname"}' localhost:5000/echo
```

And the output is from console:

```
Received Body:  {Username:noname}
2020/12/11 12:00:15 http: panic serving [::1]:52684: invalid character 'U' looking for beginning of object key string
goroutine 6 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00005caa0)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0xa2b0a0, 0xc000004820)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x499
main.echoHandler(0xacb5e0, 0xc0001340e0, 0xc000144000)
    W:/projects/snippets/golang/parsing.go:39 +0x4ec
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa8abf8, 0xacb5e0, 0xc0001340e0, 0xc000144000)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2042 +0x4b
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc00001c300, 0xacb5e0, 0xc0001340e0, 0xc000144000)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2417 +0x1b7
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc000134000, 0xacb5e0, 0xc0001340e0, 0xc000144000)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xaa
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00005caa0, 0xacba60, 0xc00001c380)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36d
```

The method: `err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)` does not work also.
Probably, the error is that when I read the body in []byte array I can not see the quotes (") in the string. How can I make the server do not miss quotes in request body?

Comment: see the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Your code does not compile: `./main.go:37:14: undefined: userJson`

Comment: Looks like an issue with curl/powershell and not with your server code.

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182698/965900

Comment: I think @super is right, because after I delete line 37 in your code and run successfully. And the server does not panic when I run `curl -d '{"Username":"noname"}' localhost:5000/echo`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your answers. The problem was in powershell:

The correct way to use json body with quotes is:

```
curl -d '{\"Username\":\"noname\"}' localhost:5000/echo
```

Comment: Yeah, m$ quality at its best!