# Uploading a file to new page of confluence Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I need to upload a file to a new page of confluence by Powershell.

I found this command to do so on the internet:

```
curl -v -S -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file=C:\Users\srvc_mdw_dev\Desktop\conf.txt" -F "comment=this is my file" "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3604482/child/attachment" | python -mjson.tool
```

The problem is I don't know the REST Resources (URL) to replace the one of the script, and also get the error:

> python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: [Curl to Invoke-webrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552704/how-to-recreate-a-working-curl-command-with-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell)

Comment: Thank you, but how can i have my X-Api-Key ?

Comment: If you don't have then you do not need to give even. except that part give the other parameters

Comment: so the script will look lke that : $json = @"
{"alert_policy":[{"enabled":"true"}]
"@
$headers = @{}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "C:\Users\srvc_mdw_dev\Desktop\conf.txt" -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Method Post   ?

Comment: Where do we define our access to confluence ? name the page ?

Comment: those details should be the -uri and headers if you do not have any then just remove it. .. URI is not the txt file. Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) of the Internet resource to which the web request is sent.This parameter supports HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and FILE values.

Comment: Sorry to ask but can you give an exemple of defining the URI with the confluence access, the file to upload and to which space and page ?